# Retrieve firebase data by date in Android

Tags: android, firebase

All I want is to store data from my android app to fire base by date and retrieve it by date. I've searched for tutorials but all I get are ones related to swift. Could someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution you have need to define date as main node like following and then after you can access it,

```
DatabaseReference timeStampPref = database.getReference().child(date);
            senderRefrence.setValue(data);//here pass your value
```

And for the access you can define query or directly Listener of your object, check following

```
 DatabaseReference timeStampPref = database.getReference().child(date);
                senderRefrence.setValue(data);//here pass your value
                        senderRefrence.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
here you can access your data based on time.

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a node inside your child node called timestamp.

Set the value of this as ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

If you have a REST API, set the value of this as a JSON object with value

{".sv":"timestamp"}

This value represents the milli seconds from epoch date. This is the only way to represent date inside firebase

You can set it inside Date object of java as it is a long value.

You can check out ordering based on orderByChild("timestamp") for ordering based on this date.